# Correct Usage of the Singleton Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I have a requirement where only one instance of `BillLines` is ever created, which is of course perfect for the singleton pattern.

Looking at [Jon's Skeet's post](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) I'm not quite understanding where I create my 'new' object (i.e. the useful object not some abstract Singleton object).

Does this appear correct to you?

```
public sealed class ContextSingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ContextSingleton> Lazy =
        new Lazy<ContextSingleton>(() => new ContextSingleton());

    public static ContextSingleton Instance { get { return Lazy.Value; } }

    private ContextSingleton()
    {
    }

    //Is this correct?  Where should I 'new' this?
    public readonly IBillLineEntities Context = new BillLines.BillLines();
}
```

Being accessed like this:

```
var contextSingleton = ContextSingleton.Instance.Context;
```

**Update**

I don't have access to the internals of `BillLines` but I need to ensure only one instance of it exists.

Comment: What do you actually *want* to be a singleton? (And are you sure you have to use this pattern? I tend to avoid it, myself...)

Comment: Does the world somehow end, if your BillLines get created a second time? Because the fact that you only need one of them is *not* a reason for a singleton the same way that needing only a single int does not mean int should be a singleton. How are you going to unit test your product, if you have a singleton?

Comment: You got it wrong. If you need `BillLines` as singleton, you need to make its constructor `private` and instance to returned from that class. Making `ContextSingleton` private has no use. Anyone can call  `new BillLines()` any number of times.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I want `BillLines` to be the singleton. @nvoigt - Yes multiple instances are causing an issue in terms of unexpected transaction promotion.

Comment: Is `BillLines` a namespace or a type? I'm worried by `new BillLines.BillLines()`...

Comment: You should ask yourself two questions: 1) Do you need to enforce that there cannot be a second instance? 2) Do you really want to access through `Class.Instance` instead of passing an instance to the class that needs it. In my experience this kind of singleton is almost never appropriate.

Comment: @Jon - It's a class named `BillLines` within a namespace of the same name.  Not the best I know.

Comment: @m.edmondson: Definitely not - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx Now, the way you've got it set up, any other code can call `new BillLines()` - so it's not really a proper singleton... so if you're relying on the rest of the code *not* instantiating it, perhaps look to dependency injection for the job of providing the same instance to all code?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks Jon I'll certainly make time to give that a read.  `BillLines` itself is something I don't have the ability to modify.  I need some kind of wrapper to ensure it's only created once.  If I go down the dependency injection route where would I instantiate `BillLines()`?

Comment: @m.edmondson - DI containers generally have a singleton lifetime defined. The first time a piece of code needs a `Billines` the container will instantiate it and will the reuse that instance for all subsequent uses.

Comment: @RobH - Thanks I'll investigate this route instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @JonSkeet and @RobH I went down the dependency injection route.  I picked [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) and this does the job as I expected:

```
public class NinjectBindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IBillLineEntities>.To<BillLines.BillLines>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume `BillLines` should be your `Instance` variable.

It should look like this:

```
public static class ContextSingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<BillLines> _instance =
        new Lazy<BillLines>(() => new BillLines());

    public static BillLines Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }

    private ContextSingleton()
    {
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
ContextSingleton.Instance
```

**Edit**

This answer was targeting the creation of a singleton about a specific class. If other people have access to your `BillLines` class and can create their own instance of it, then you should probably rethink what you're trying to do. If you do control the exposure of your `BillLines` class, you should make it so it is only exposed in the internal implementation of the singleton you're exposing, so no other person can create a `new BillLines` as they see fit.

Comment: -1 Btw, This is not a singleton. What stops client from creating instances of `BillLines` themselves?

Comment: Why is this not a singleton?

Comment: He shouldn't expose the `BillLines` as a public class to the client, it should be internal to the underlying implementation.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That's not what singleton mean. It means you can create **atmost** only one instance. If your code itself creates `new BillLines()` how does this makes it a singleton?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It doesn't prevent creation of additional instances. Siriam is applying a rather strict definition of singleton where the class has a private constructor and it's not possible to create additional instances. I prefer to see singletons as a broader concept where you only need one instance. That broader definition also includes variants where an IoC container simply creates only one instance without the class itself enforcing that limit.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel This question was about the creation of a proper singleton. The OP specifies nothing about being able to create a `new BillLines` anywhere, but simply asking if he's generating the singleton correctly. If he controls `BillLines`, he can make sure he doesn't expose it to whomever needs to be consuming this singleton.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I understand, but it really depends on who are the consumers of this code. If it's his team members, then this can be inforced by policy. If it is some sort of 3rd party API, then he should hide the internal `BillLines` from the outside world.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov *This question was about the creation of a proper singleton* yes, that's the question but your answer doesn't adhere the main criteria of singleton. From wiki singleton definition is : *Singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object*. This answer ain't do that. This is just a static class providing instance. You can name it `SomeStaticClassReturningInstancePattern` and not singleton pattern.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Looking at the OPs original post, you can understand what he's trying to achieve. I was simply correcting him to use the proper `Instance` property. This isn't a philosophical debate about how he should be protecting other people from creating an instance of his class, this is rather much more of a technical question. If he wanted to know how to protect his class from being created outside of the singleton scoped, he should of asked exactly that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Op asked that right in the first statement(atleast for me). *I have a requirement where only one instance of `BillLines` is ever created* Is this answer does that? You want to argue anymore?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I've added a declaimer to my answer. I am assuming the OP knows the meaning of a singleton, and he knows that if other people can create a new instance of whatever class he's wrapping, this will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this?

```
public class BillLines
{
    private BillLines()
    {
    }
    private static BillLines _billLines = null;

    public static BillLines Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_billLines == null)
                _billLines = new BillLines();
            return _billLines;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not thread safe. The OP's code uses `Lazy<T>` which encapsulates thread safe creation of a single instance. Using it is generally the best choice.